# Is there a JCheckBox listener for itemstateNOTchanged?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcheckbox

i am looking for a way to add all checkboxes in a list, that are executing the setSelected(bool) method in JCheckBox.
Example:

```
//all Checkboxes are previously false
cb1.setSelected(true);
cb2.setSelected(true);
cb3.setSelected(false);
cb4.setSelected(false);
```

ItemListener would only trigger on cb1 and cb2.
ActionListener would not even trigger at all (only on doClick).

Is there a listener that would trigger, even the state does not change but the method setSelected(bool) was executed?

Thank you =)

Comment: I suspect that you may have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution may be to use a completely different approach. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to highlight (setBorder) all checkboxes that are "touched" in a specific code-area (cb1,cb2,cb3,...) even the state is not changed. That code-area is pretty big and should stay that way it is. In that listener that i am looking for i would add that component to my list. In the end all checkboxes in that list get a red border.

Comment: What are you calling "touched"  ?

Comment: All checkboxes that are calling setSelected(). I could add all components in that code-area by hand, but that would be pretty time consuming and in case of maintanance it would be very messy.

Comment: Maybe you could override `setSelected` ?

Comment: @Berger: I'm thinking that the solution to whatever his problem is, lies in modifying his model/controller, not his view.

Comment: Yes, already thought of that. But i would have to touch the netbeans generated code for this solution. I wanted to avoid this. But if there is no other way to listen to the method-execution (setSelected) otherwise, i would go with that. Thanks for the hint.